# Cannot connect to SQL Server from Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 from Excel 2007. When it tries to connect I get the error:

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()).]Invalid connection.

---

#### Steps to Reproduce

- On the **Data** tab, in the **Get External Data** group, click **From Other Sources**, and then click **From SQL Server**:

[image]

- type the name of the SQL Server computer in the **Server name** box.
- To enter a database user name and password, click **Use the following User Name and Password**, and then type your user name and password in the corresponding **User Name** and **Password** boxes:

[image]

---

#### Additional information

- I *can* connect to SQL Server from **SQL Server Management Studio**:
  [image]
- I *can* connect to SQL Server with **`telnet`**:

  ```
  C:\Users\Ian>telnet avenger 1433
  ```
- SQL Server *is* listening on port 1433:
  [image]
- Excel *does* connect, and receive response traffic from the SQL Server:
  [image]
- I *can* `ping` the server:

  ```
  C:\Users\Ian>ping avenger

  Pinging avenger.newland.com [192.168.1.244] with 32 bytes of data:
  Reply from 192.168.1.244: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
  Reply from 192.168.1.244: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
  Reply from 192.168.1.244: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
  Reply from 192.168.1.244: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

  Ping statistics for 192.168.1.244:
      Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
  Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
      Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
  ```
- Trying to connect by IP address (rather than by name) has no effect:
  [image]
- Windows Firewall is *not* running on the server:
  [image]

Comment: Although it's been a while, thanks for including so much detail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that you're actually using a named instance and the SQL Native client allows you to get away with using `AVENGER` as the server name but the `DBNETLIB` (which I believe is the old SQL Client) is more demanding.

Are you sure it's not `AVENGER\SQLEXPRESS,1433`?

Comment: Turns out it *is* that. It should be noted that simply `AVENGER\SQLEXPRESS` didn't work; i **had** to include the (standard) port.

Comment: More hazardous guesses, but the computer that Excel is running on cannot communicate with the SQL Browser service on the server (or the service is not running).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

An old application had registered an old version of `SQLOLEDB.DLL` in

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

Fixed by running these commands:

```
regsvr32 "c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ole DB\sqloledb.dll"
```

and

```
del c:\WINDOWS\system32\sqloledb.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the SQL server data server name fixed this for me in Excel 2013

1. Connect to the database server with SQL Server Management Studio
2. Right-Click the server in the *Object Explorer*
3. Select Properties
4. Use the *Name* value listed on the server's General Properties page

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when connecting from Access 2007 to SQL Server 2016. The solution in my case was to enable the TCP/IP protocol (in SQL Server Configuration Manager).